When rendering an animation, how can I output multiple images per frame with different view transforms?
What I basically need to do, is output the full color render (without alpha channel), and the alpha channel (black and white) of each frame of an animation I'm rendering. Only issue, is that I'm using Filmic view transform, but the alpha channel renders need to be in Standard view transform, so the values will be 0-1.
Is there any way these could be rendered in one go? Of course this could be done by rendering the sequence twice, but with each frame taking upwards of 30 minutes, it seems like a huge waste, when all I need is change the view transform.
While I'm at it, I also need to change the "Look" from high contrast to none respectively.

As I understand it, you are compositing your shot in another software (or in Blender in a second time). Then I would suggest treating your image in post, changing color space usually being quite simple to achieve. Otherwise, does the Color Space node achieve what you are looking for https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/converter/color_space.html ? Also, Filmic has been replaced by AgX which is of better quality.

Thanks for the reply, however this node isn't doing what I need unfortunately. It changes the color space, but I need to change the view transform. I'll see if I can apply these view transforms in post by rendering to EXR or something.

Isn't View Transform only the Blender name for color space ? Plus, you don't need to use EXR to change your color space, PNG with 16bits should work with no artifacts. I'm not totally sure though.

Not exactly. The naming of the menus is a bit weird, but under Color management, there are dropdowns called View transform and sequencer. If you open Sequencer, you'll see it says "color space", and it has the same options as the convert colorspace node, but there is no node to my knowledge that lets you change the view transform. I also have to render to EXR, because my ranges are way above 1, so a png would be just pure white.
